# Weights of mixed sheaves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

In Weil II, a mixed sheaf is defined as a sheaf admitting a finite filtration with punctually pure quotients, and its weights are defined as the weights of the graded pieces. Are the weights of a mixed sheaf well-defined? How to see that?

Comment: It would help if you said a little more about what you don't understand.  Are you comfortable with the case $X$ is a point?

Comment: @S.Carnahan what point? If you mean the spectrum of a field of positive characteristic, I don't think I am.

Comment: In that case, you get an $\ell$-adic vector space equipped with an endomorphism, and a filtration whose quotients are eigenspaces.  The question is: do the eigenvalues of the quotients depend on the choice of filtration?